# Regex to extract bibliography text from paragraph - Python

Tags: python, regex

In my `Python` task, I've a string (Paragraph) of bibliography that I want to parse into list of strings.

here is whole string

```
A. Berger and H. Printz. 1998. Recognition perfor- mance of a large-scale dependency-grammar lan- guage model. In Int'l Conference on Spoken Lan- guage Processing (ICSLP'98), Sydney, Australia. A. Blum. 1992. Learning boolean functions in an infinite attribute space. Machine Learning, 9(4):373-386. E. Brill. 1995. Transformation-based error-driven learning and natural language processing: A case study in part of speech tagging. Computational Linguistics, 21(4):543-565. C. Chelba and F. Jelinek. 1998. Exploiting syntac- tic structure for language modeling. In COLING- A CL '98. C. Cumby and D. Roth. 2000. Relational repre- sentations that facilitate learning. In Proc. of the International Conference on the Principles of Knowledge Representation and Reasoning. To ap- pear. I. Dagan, L. Lee, and F. Pereira. 1999. Similarity- based models of word cooccurrence probabilities. Machine Learning, 34(1-3):43-69. A. R. Golding and D. Roth. 1999. A Winnow based approach to context-sensitive spelling correction. Machine Learning, 34(1-3):107-130. Special Issue on Machine Learning and Natural Language. F. Jelinek. 1998. Statistical Methods for Speech Recognition. MIT Press. D. Jurafsky and J. H. Martin. 200. Speech and Lan- guage Processing. Prentice Hall. L. Lee and F. Pereira. 1999. Distributional similar- ity models: Clustering vs. nearest neighbors. In A CL 99, pages 33-40. L. Lee. 1999. Measure of distributional similarity. In A CL 99, pages 25-32. N. Littlestone. 1988. Learning quickly when irrel- evant attributes abound: A new linear-threshold algorithm. Machine Learning, 2:285-318. M. Munoz, V. Punyakanok, D. Roth, and D. Zimak. 1999. A learning approach to shallow parsing. In EMNLP-VLC'99, the Joint SIGDAT Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Pro- cessing and Very Large Corpora, June. A. Ratnaparkhi, J. Reynar, and S. Roukos. 1994. A maximum entropy model for prepositional phrase attachment. In ARPA, Plainsboro, N J, March. R. Rosenfeld. 1996. A maximum entropy approach to adaptive statistical language modeling. Com- puter, Speech and Language, 10. D. Roth and D. Zelenko. 1998. Part of speech tagging using a network of linear separators. In COLING-ACL 98, The 17th International Conference on Computational Linguistics, pages 1136-1142. D. Roth. 1998. Learning to resolve natural language ambiguities: A unified approach. In Proc. Na- tional Conference on Artificial Intelligence, pages 806-813. D. Roth. 1999. Learning in natural language. In Proc. of the International Joint Conference of Ar- tificial Intelligence, pages 898-904. P. Tapanainen and T. Jrvinen. 1997. A non- projective dependency parser. In In Proceedings of the 5th Conference on Applied Natural Lan- guage Processing, Washington DC. D. Yarowsky. 1994. Decision lists for lexical ambi- guity resolution: application to accent restoration in Spanish and French. In Proc. of the Annual Meeting of the A CL, pages 88-95. D. Yuret. 1998. Discovery of Linguistic Relations Using Lexical Attraction. Ph.D. thesis, MIT. 131
```

and this is how I want the output...

```
A. Berger and H. Printz. 1998. Recognition performance of a large-scale dependency-grammar language model. In Int'l Conference on Spoken Language Processing (ICSLP'98), Sydney, Australia.


A. Blum. 1992. Learning boolean functions in an infinite attribute space. Machine Learning, 9(4):373-386.

E. Brill. 1995. Transformation-based error-driven learning and natural language processing: A case study in part of speech tagging. Computational Linguistics, 21(4):543-565.

C. Chelba and F. Jelinek. 1998. Exploiting syntactic structure for language modeling. In COLINGA CL '98.

C. Cumby and D. Roth. 2000. Relational representations that facilitate learning. In Proc. of the International Conference on the Principles of Knowledge Representation and Reasoning. To appear.

I. Dagan, L. Lee, and F. Pereira. 1999. Similaritybased models of word cooccurrence probabilities. Machine Learning, 34(1-3):43-69.

A. R. Golding and D. Roth. 1999. A Winnow based approach to context-sensitive spelling correction. Machine Learning, 34(1-3):107-130. Special Issue on Machine Learning and Natural Language.

F. Jelinek. 1998. Statistical Methods for Speech Recognition. MIT Press.

D. Jurafsky and J. H. Martin. 200. Speech and Language Processing. Prentice Hall.
```

and so on...

I tried different regex but unable to get a proper result. because string does not have any specific end.

But every new string is starting with Author Name(s) following by year and then paper name.

For example in first string AuthorName (`A. Berger`) following by an `and` and another Author Name (`H. printz.`) and then Year `1998.`. But in 2nd String, Authorname (`A. Blum.`) following by Year `1992.`.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: On what pattern the string is getting into new line? Please do mention that. Because without a proper pattern; regex won't work.

Comment: Updated question..

Comment: This is not a pattern; [pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) means something whose occurrence is common throughout. How do someone know where the pattern ends? or what is your end marker to split it into a new line.

Comment: Actually that is the issue.. Pattern is not same and there is no any end marker.. that's why I posted it here that may be someone can get the idea...

Comment: Then surely this is too vague to be handled by regular expressions. You have to go for text mining. [**This**](https://medium.com/towards-artificial-intelligence/text-mining-in-python-steps-and-examples-78b3f8fd913b) might help to get you started.

Comment: Alright... Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unable to get a proper result. because string does not have any specific end.   But every new string is starting with Author Name(s) following by year`

This may be enough. I've written a regex that *`works on your whole sample`*,
however it is still subjective. Any add or subtract of name form or punctuation
will blow it out of the water.

```
((?:(?<![a-zA-Z])[A-Z]\.[ \t]+)+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(?<![a-zA-Z])[A-Z]\.[ \t]+)+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)*(?:[ \t]*,)?(?:[ \t]+and[ \t]+(?:(?<![a-zA-Z])[A-Z]\.[ \t]+)+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)*[ \t]*\.[ \t]*\d{4}[ \t]*\.)(?!\S)
```

replace with `\r\n\1`

see sample here -> https://regex101.com/r/ylZKDH/1

***python sub sample per request***

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> biblioStr = '''A. Berger and H. Printz. 1998. Recognition perfor- mance of a large-scale dependency-grammar lan- guage model. In Int'l Conference on Spoken Lan- guage Processing (ICSLP'98), Sydney, Australia. A. Blum. 1992. Learning boo
lean functions in an infinite attribute space. Machine Learning, 9(4):373-386. E. Brill. 1995. Transformation-based error-driven learning and natural language processing: A case study in part of speech tagging. Computational Linguistics, 21
(4):543-565. C. Chelba and F. Jelinek. 1998. Exploiting syntac- tic structure for language modeling. In COLING- A CL '98. C. Cumby and D. Roth. 2000. Relational repre- sentations that facilitate learning. In Proc. of the International Confe
rence on the Principles of Knowledge Representation and Reasoning. To ap- pear. I. Dagan, L. Lee, and F. Pereira. 1999. Similarity- based models of word cooccurrence probabilities. Machine Learning, 34(1-3):43-69. A. R. Golding and D. Roth.
 1999. A Winnow based approach to context-sensitive spelling correction. Machine Learning, 34(1-3):107-130. Special Issue on Machine Learning and Natural Language. F. Jelinek. 1998. Statistical Methods for Speech Recognition. MIT Press. D.
Jurafsky and J. H. Martin. 200. Speech and Lan- guage Processing. Prentice Hall. L. Lee and F. Pereira. 1999. Distributional similar- ity models: Clustering vs. nearest neighbors. In A CL 99, pages 33-40. L. Lee. 1999. Measure of distributi
onal similarity. In A CL 99, pages 25-32. N. Littlestone. 1988. Learning quickly when irrel- evant attributes abound: A new linear-threshold algorithm. Machine Learning, 2:285-318. M. Munoz, V. Punyakanok, D. Roth, and D. Zimak. 1999. A lea
rning approach to shallow parsing. In EMNLP-VLC'99, the Joint SIGDAT Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Pro- cessing and Very Large Corpora, June. A. Ratnaparkhi, J. Reynar, and S. Roukos. 1994. A maximum entropy model for
prepositional phrase attachment. In ARPA, Plainsboro, N J, March. R. Rosenfeld. 1996. A maximum entropy approach to adaptive statistical language modeling. Com- puter, Speech and Language, 10. D. Roth and D. Zelenko. 1998. Part of speech ta
gging using a network of linear separators. In COLING-ACL 98, The 17th International Conference on Computational Linguistics, pages 1136-1142. D. Roth. 1998. Learning to resolve natural language ambiguities: A unified approach. In Proc. Na-
 tional Conference on Artificial Intelligence, pages 806-813. D. Roth. 1999. Learning in natural language. In Proc. of the International Joint Conference of Ar- tificial Intelligence, pages 898-904. P. Tapanainen and T. Jrvinen. 1997. A non
- projective dependency parser. In In Proceedings of the 5th Conference on Applied Natural Lan- guage Processing, Washington DC. D. Yarowsky. 1994. Decision lists for lexical ambi- guity resolution: application to accent restoration in Span
ish and French. In Proc. of the Annual Meeting of the A CL, pages 88-95. D. Yuret. 1998. Discovery of Linguistic Relations Using Lexical Attraction. Ph.D. thesis, MIT. 131
... '''
>>>
>>> Rx = re.compile( r"((?:(?<![a-zA-Z])[A-Z]\.[ \t]+)+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(?<![a-zA-Z])[A-Z]\.[ \t]+)+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)*(?:[ \t]*,)?(?:[ \t]+and[ \t]+(?:(?<![a-zA-Z])[A-Z]\.[ \t]+)+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)*[ \t]*\.[ \t]*\d{4}[ \t]*\.)(?!
\S)" )
>>>
>>> print (re.sub( Rx, r'\r\n\1', biblioStr ))

A. Berger and H. Printz. 1998. Recognition perfor- mance of a large-scale dependency-grammar lan- guage model. In Int'l Conference on Spoken Lan- guage Processing (ICSLP'98), Sydney, Australia.
A. Blum. 1992. Learning boolean functions in an infinite attribute space. Machine Learning, 9(4):373-386.
E. Brill. 1995. Transformation-based error-driven learning and natural language processing: A case study in part of speech tagging. Computational Linguistics, 21(4):543-565.
C. Chelba and F. Jelinek. 1998. Exploiting syntac- tic structure for language modeling. In COLING- A CL '98.
C. Cumby and D. Roth. 2000. Relational repre- sentations that facilitate learning. In Proc. of the International Conference on the Principles of Knowledge Representation and Reasoning. To ap- pear.
I. Dagan, L. Lee, and F. Pereira. 1999. Similarity- based models of word cooccurrence probabilities. Machine Learning, 34(1-3):43-69.
A. R. Golding and D. Roth. 1999. A Winnow based approach to context-sensitive spelling correction. Machine Learning, 34(1-3):107-130. Special Issue on Machine Learning and Natural Language.
F. Jelinek. 1998. Statistical Methods for Speech Recognition. MIT Press. D. Jurafsky and J. H. Martin. 200. Speech and Lan- guage Processing. Prentice Hall.
L. Lee and F. Pereira. 1999. Distributional similar- ity models: Clustering vs. nearest neighbors. In A CL 99, pages 33-40.
L. Lee. 1999. Measure of distributional similarity. In A CL 99, pages 25-32.
N. Littlestone. 1988. Learning quickly when irrel- evant attributes abound: A new linear-threshold algorithm. Machine Learning, 2:285-318.
M. Munoz, V. Punyakanok, D. Roth, and D. Zimak. 1999. A learning approach to shallow parsing. In EMNLP-VLC'99, the Joint SIGDAT Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Pro- cessing and Very Large Corpora, June.
A. Ratnaparkhi, J. Reynar, and S. Roukos. 1994. A maximum entropy model for prepositional phrase attachment. In ARPA, Plainsboro, N J, March.
R. Rosenfeld. 1996. A maximum entropy approach to adaptive statistical language modeling. Com- puter, Speech and Language, 10.
D. Roth and D. Zelenko. 1998. Part of speech tagging using a network of linear separators. In COLING-ACL 98, The 17th International Conference on Computational Linguistics, pages 1136-1142.
D. Roth. 1998. Learning to resolve natural language ambiguities: A unified approach. In Proc. Na- tional Conference on Artificial Intelligence, pages 806-813.
D. Roth. 1999. Learning in natural language. In Proc. of the International Joint Conference of Ar- tificial Intelligence, pages 898-904.
P. Tapanainen and T. Jrvinen. 1997. A non- projective dependency parser. In In Proceedings of the 5th Conference on Applied Natural Lan- guage Processing, Washington DC.
D. Yarowsky. 1994. Decision lists for lexical ambi- guity resolution: application to accent restoration in Spanish and French. In Proc. of the Annual Meeting of the A CL, pages 88-95.
D. Yuret. 1998. Discovery of Linguistic Relations Using Lexical Attraction. Ph.D. thesis, MIT. 131
```

Comment: Cool. How can I add this substitution (\r\n\1) in code??

Comment: I'll put up a python demo for you

Comment: Thank you for this favor.. :)

Comment: Please accept this if it reasonably answered your question, otherwise some maven downvoted this, can you believe it ?

Comment: And Sorry for downvote (who ever did that may be share the reason as well), SO has its own rules and regulations...